# Displaying Google Map on a UIWebView

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, maps, directions

i have [this url](http://maps.google.com.br/maps?t=m&saddr=SOMEWHERE&daddr=SOMEWHERE%20ELSE):

If i open it up in the iphone or in the ipad, the uiwebview displays the step-by-step to reach  the final place.

I want to display the MAP by default.

Is there any way to do that? I mean, with some kind of adaptation of the url?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question,
according to [Apple URL Scheme Reference - Map Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)

it seems that we don't have an option to do that.

besides, there's an article building a WEB APPs, I'll post the link in case it might be helpful

[Location in iPhone Web Apps](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/location-iphone-web-apps)